# Create a FILE in C

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, microchip

I'm using MPLAB C32. I want to map my peripherals in streams, in order to do something like:

```
FILE* uart2 = fopen("UART2", 9600, param2, param3);
```

or just

```
FILE* uart2 = fopen("UART");
```

and then use fprintf to write on it:

```
fprintf(uart2, fmt, params);
```

What's the usual way of creating a FILE? Without having a filesystem, I just want to map peripherals on it.

Comment: Errr... what's the question exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MPLAB C Compiler User's Guide, Document DS51686B, (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51686B.pdf), the library has support for wiring up devices to the stdio facilities. An as luck would have it, UART 2 is set to stdin/stdout/stderr by default, but only output will work since `_mon_getc` isn't implemented by default.  If you define your own, that should enable input from UART 2 via stdin.

> 2.3 Standard I/O:
>
> The standard input/output library functions support two modes of
>   operation, Simple and Full. The Simple mode supports I/O via a two
>   function interface on a single character device used for stdout, stdin
>   and stderr. The Full mode supports the complete set of standard I/O
>   functions. The library will use Full mode if the application calls
>   fopen, otherwise Simple mode is used.
>
> Simple mode performs I/O using four functions, _mon_puts, _mon_write,
>   _mon_getc and _mon_putc, to perform the raw device I/O. The default
>   implementation of _mon_getc always returns failure (i.e., by default,
>   character input is not available). The default implementation of
>   _mon_putc writes a character to UART2. It is assumed that the
>   application has performed any necessary initialization of the UART.
>   The default implementations of _mon_puts and _mon_write both simply
>   call _mon_putc iteratively. All four functions are defined as weak
>   functions, and so may be overridden by the user application if
>   different functionality is desired. See the “32-Bit Language Tools
>   Libraries” for detailed information on these functions.

If you need more control than that, a description of how to customize the runtime to 'connect' your devices to the stdio facilities of the compiler's runtime library is documented in the MPLAB C32 "32-Bit Language Tools Libraries" document DS51685 (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB%20C32%20Libraries.pdf).

It looks like most of the functions required to support 'full mode' are documented in "2.18  MISCELLANEOUS FUNCTIONS"

Answer (score 4):

You have to write drivers for each peripheral. Also you have to redefine your FILE* so you can have enough information to call appropriate driver. And also you need to redefine fopen and fprintf functions too. But this is pointless. I don't recommend this kind of practice. There's already built library [PIC32 Peripheral Library](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en554265) is out. I recommend to use it.

Comment: I have drivers for all of the peripherals, but I need to have a standard way to execute write and read operations. I could develop that "interface" but using an already standard way seams better, I just don't understand how can I create a FILE.

Comment: FILE is a structure which contains enough information about using your interface. You don't have to look for file.h for it. I would store function pointers (for read&write) and peripheral specific arguments (would be one or two bytes which contains used uart number and/or baud rate etc) So when you call fprintf fprintf can call peripheral driver with arguments and voila! You wrote data to uart.